# My.Settings "Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds."

Tags: vb.net, forms, combobox

I have two forms with combo boxes. The combo box values are stored in My.Settings.testDevices. (System.Collections.Specialized.String.Collection) with a scope of User.

The second form adds the ability to add items to testDevices, and then upon exit it updates My.Settings.testDevices.

Now, *only if I make a change to the settings* (adding items only), when I exit back to the main form (which remains loaded throughout the process), my application crashes with the following message:

"Additional information: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds."

As I understand it, this might be a concurrency issue, however I'm not sure.

My code:

In my main form Load event: (to load from My.Settings)

```
   testDevicesComboBoxMain.Items.Clear()
   My.Settings.testDevices.CopyTo(mainFormTestDevices, 0)
   testDevicesComboBoxMain.Items.AddRange(mainFormTestDevices)
```

Where "testDevicesComboBoxMain" is the combo box on the main form.

On the secondary form Close Event: (to save to My.Settings)

```
    Dim items(testDevicesComboBox.Items.Count - 1) As String
    testDevicesComboBox.Items.CopyTo(items, 0)
    My.Settings.testDevices.Clear()
    My.Settings.testDevices.AddRange(items)

    My.Settings.Save()
```

I have found similar questions on here, but none with answers that I understand :P

As I am a beginner with vb.net, could any answers be provided in an easy to understand form please!

Thanks.

I forgot to add:

```
Public items(My.Settings.testDevices.Count - 1) As String
Public mainFormTestDevices(My.Settings.testDevices.Count - 1) As String
```

I tried setting separate declarations just in case there was some kind of conflict. These obviously do the same thing, just with different names.

Comment: What is `mainFormTestDevices`?  Rather than hopscotching thru temp things, Save the changes to settings, then create a method on the "main" form which tell it to reload the cbo from Settings.

Comment: I just realised I forgot to add my Public variables - I have revised my question.

Comment: `Public items(My.Settings.testDevices.Count - 1) As String` the size is only set once - the varaible is not going to monitor Settings and make itself bigger when you add an item.  So when you try to copy more Settings values to it you get that error - the destination *is* too small

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a For loop to read from My.Settings.

```
    For Each i As String In My.Settings.testDevices
        testDevicesComboBoxMain.Items.Add(i)
    Next
```

This seems to have cured the problem, and may perhaps be a more "modern" way of doing it?